# Looks like keras Normalization layer doesn't denormalize properly

Tags: python, keras

I want to use keras Normalization layer to "denormalize" my output.
The doc for this object says the argument "invert=True" does exactly that, but it doesn't behave as I thought at all...

I tried to isolate the problem and show that it doesn't compute the inverse of the normalization

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from keras import layers

norm = layers.Normalization()
denorm = layers.Normalization(invert=True)
y = np.array([[10.0], 
              [20.0], 
              [30.0]])
norm.adapt(y)
denorm.adapt(y)
```

Here I checked the mean and variance and it looks like it is the same for both, all good for now.

```
print(norm(20))
print(denorm(0))
```

I get as output 0 and 163.29932 instead of 0 and 20...
It looks like the denormalization adds the mean and then multiply by std instead of multiplying by std first.

The keras version is probably relevant here :

`print(keras.__version__)`

Output : '2.10.0'

Comment: New here, and my question slowly transformed from "what is going on" to "looks like it's wrong, am I missing something ?". If I'm pretty sure the keras function has a problem, I guess the question doesn't fit well on stackoverflow and I should try to talk about it on github or something ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked in the code and found that it was indeed an error (adding the mean and then multiplying by the standard deviation).

I opened a pull request to fix this problem and it has been accepted, so it should be fixed in a short while.

Comment: Update : the bugfix is not yet part of tensorflow but is part of tf-nightly (tensorflow with the latest bugfixes)